# Forking on Google Code (or any other SVN hosting)

Tags: svn, git, open-source, mercurial, fork

Sites like [github](http://help.github.com/forking/), [bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org/help/Collaborating#forking) provides an excellent/useful feature of "forking" projects. This allows one to simply fork a project and work on their desired features (before submitting it to the projector owner and getting commit access).

How is this workflow best achieved for [SVN](http://subversion.tigris.org/) projects (especially the various ones hosted on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/hosting/) that are still using SVN)?

**Clarification**: I know about svn diff, but want a solution where I can do several intermittent commits before submitting the changes back to the author (the owner of the SVN repo). Bonus points for making this "fork" as easy as clicking a button (I wonder if github/bitbucket will ever have this feature of automatically cloning a SVN repo).

Answer (score 5):

Since you already seem to be familiar with git, you can use [git svn](http://orestis.gr/blog/2008/08/23/git-svn-tutorial/). You can fetch the SVN project like this (`-s` indicates the standard trunk/branches/tags layout):

```
git svn clone url://path/to/repo -s
```

You can push each local git commit as a separate svn commit like this:

```
git svn dcommit
```

It is common practice to use the `git rebase` command to clean up and simplify the commit history before pushing changes to svn.

**edit**: for mercurial there are also [several extensions](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/WorkingWithSubversion) to interoperate with an SVN repository, though none appear to be as mature as git-svn.

Comment: Sridhar: Don't worry if you're more familiar with Mercurial -- give hgsubversion as try and see if it works for you: http://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion/ People use it daily, please come ask in #hgsubversion on irc.freenode.net.

Answer (score 0):

How is it achieved?  The same way it's always been, you young whippersnapper!

Why, in my day, after walking home from school (uphill, in the snow), we had to create a diff of our changes and submit it to the maintainer (or maintainer's mailing list/group) manually!

You'll find the command **svn diff** to be of use to you in this task.  It will create a unified diff of your changes suitable for submission upstream.

Comment: Forking a DVCS enables one to do intermittent commits. Whereas relying on 'svn diff' alone is to leave one's working copy vulnerable (eg: disk crash).

Comment: Indeed, but that is a function of the process forced by the toolset.  You can't make an apple taste like an orange, no matter how much paint you apply.